# Push this.props' value to the state of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to push values which are coming from props to the state.

I have a value, `this.props.faculty = 19` which comes to me from parent.
Now, each time I get a value from parent, I want to push it to my state in child. So, in the end in my child I would have something like this:

```
this.state.faculties = [19, 20, 13 etc]
```

How can I do that?
I use `React.js` with `TypeScript`.

I tried:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, faculties: this.props.faculty, });
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: @ChrisG yeah, I tried componentDidUpdate like this: `componentDidUpdate() {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            faculties: this.props.faculty,
        });
    }`
It gives me null in state, no differences.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { if (this.props.faculty != prevProps.faculty) this.setState({ faculties: [...this.state.faculties, this.props.faculty] }); }` Note that this will only work if the same component instance keeps being mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` is called after every re-render, since you use setState in it without conditional check, it will result in an infinite loop

You must check if the previous and `currentValue` from props is different and only then push it. Also use functional setState to update the state by adding an item

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.faculty !== this.props.faculty) {
      // This assumes, faculty cannot contain duplicate values in simultaneous updates
      this.setState(prevState=> ({ 
           faculties: prevState.faculties.concat([this.props.faculty])
      }));
  }
}
```